# Node Mongoose Array of Object return [Object]

Tags: express, mongoose

I have been digging in this issue for quite sometime, searched google and stack. None of the options offered really fixed the issue I have.
It seems to be quite a bit of hassle using an Array of Object in Mongoose.

So here is the schema:

```
{
  media: {
    social: [{Social: String, handler: String}],
    profilePic: String
  }
}
```

Here is the input:

```
[ 
  { Social: 'Facebook', handler: 'user' },
  { Social: 'Twitter', handler: 'useruser' },
  { Social: 'Youtube', handler: 'someuser' } 
]
```

Here is the output:

```
media: { profilePic: 'somelink', social: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] }
```

Here is what I attempted:

I tried doing a loop thru the array and push it to

```
schema.media.social.push(data)
schema.media.social = data
```

On the schema I tried:

```
social: [Array]
social: [{type: Array}]
social: {}
social: []
social: [{social: {
  type: String},
handler: {
  type: String}
}]
```

Even if I hard code:

```
schema.media.social = {Social: 'Facebook', handler: 'user}
schema.media.social.push({Social: 'Facebook', handler: 'user})
schema.media.social = [{Social: 'Facebook', handler: 'user}]
```

No avail in anything, I continue to get [Object] as output.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after digging and trying I found a solution that works for now.

the array of objects was 2 layers deep and apparently doesn't work that way, so I just had to bring it back to root and it worked.

If this is really the only way to work with nested array and objects, then mongoDb sucks though.

```
{
  social: [],
  profilePic: String
}
```

Comment: Wasn't it because you were using `console.log(data)` to print the stuff? Pure `console.log` shortens the ouptut. Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))` instead.